# Let $n \in \mathbb{N} $, $n \geq 2$. Prove that there are $\infty$ m so that $\tau(m)=n$.

Tags: solution-verification, divisibility

As the title says,

Prove that there are infinite m so that $\tau(m)=n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 2$.

If m is a primenumber, the statement is obvious as there are infite primenumbers with $\tau(m)=2$

For composite numbers, I am a bit lost as how to approach the problem.
My guess would be, as $\tau(m)=\prod_{i=1}^r (e_{i} + 1)$, to prove that there are infinitely many numbers with a similar prime factorization, like:

$p_{1}^{e_1}…p_{r}^{e_r}$ and $f_{1}^{e_1}…f_{r}^{e_r}$

With the same **r** and **e**.

I am not asking for a solution, but rather a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Assuming $\tau(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$, you can prove this just looking at powers of primes (and knowing there are infinitely many primes).

Comment: @RobertShore I was aiming at this approach too, but would it be rigid enough to say there are infinitely many prime numbers and therefore there have to be numbers sharing the same r (as in the question above) with the same e?

Comment: I think that's much more complicated than you need to make it.  Just use the answer of @tatiana below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\tau(p^{n-1})=(n-1)+1=n$$
for any prime $p$.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn‘t asking for a solution but your answer made me see where I went wrong. I actually had this approach right under my nose the whole time, thanks again!